# Alternatives to Portlets

Tags: jakarta-ee, portlet

Are there any good alternatives to portlets that can be deployed in a Java EE server?  A search seems to only really suggest [Google Gadgets](https://developers.google.com/gadgets/) which, please correct me if I'm wrong, need to be deployed on Google's servers.

I want something that behaves like a portlet within my Java EE application - without the painful complexity of having to embed something like [Pluto](http://portals.apache.org/pluto/).

Answer (score 0):

Google Gadgets do need a container to run them. The most prevalent nowadays is OpenSocial:
http://opensocial.org/

You might also like to look at something like the Apache Wookie project, which creates widgets:
http://wookie.apache.org/docs/widgets.html

Of the three technologies (gadgets, widgets and portlets) you are better off in the long run with portlets as they are used much more widely.